# Does my opponent need to prove his creature has morph?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-regular-rel, mtg-face-down-cards

I'm playing against an opponent who, for whatever reason, doesn't want to give away more information than they have to. (Perhaps they're trying to limit what is known about their strategy, their decklist, or their tells)

My opponent is one damage off lethal, but any creature will get him there. (Let's say I know he has a [Might of the Masses](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMight%20of%20the%20Masses%5d) in hand.) He plays a morph creature face down, swings (and casts his might of the Masses) and wins. Can I demand he prove the card had morph? Doing so gives me information in our next round that I shouldn't have, but it also proves that he didn't put just any card face down for {3}

Is the only solution to get a judge involved? What if he already started scooping his cards back into his deck? Should I have asked a judge to verify that the facedown creature had morph before it resolved? If so, it seems unreasonable to call over a judge every time a morph creature is played. In this instance it's clear the creature was crucial in the moment, but in other cases the creature could have been on the field for several turns, and it didn't look so conspicuous when it was played.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Rule 708.9](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Face_down) says this:

> If a face-down permanent or a face-down component of a merged permanent moves from the battlefield to any other zone, its owner must reveal it to all players as they move it. If a face-down spell moves from the stack to any zone other than the battlefield, its owner must reveal it to all players as they move it. If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players. At the end of each game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells must be revealed to all players.

There is no way for a game to end without one of these things happening to each face down permanent, so every face down permanent must be revealed one way or another by the end of the game.

Comment: Right, the player *at some point* will have to prove that the card does have morph, but doesn't do so when playing it. The proof comes at essentially the last opportunity - when the morphed permanent moves zones and stops being a morphed permanent, or when the game ends.

Answer (score 31):

Failing to reveal a face down creature with Morph at the end of the game is treated as a Game Loss.

Per the [MTG Infraction Procedure Guide](https://media.wpn.wizards.com/attachements/mtg_ipg_12jul19_en.pdf):

> 3.2.  Game Play Error —  Hidden Card Error
>
> **Penalty**
>
> Warning
>
> **Definition**
>
> A player commits an error in the game that cannot be corrected by only publicly available information. It is not a Hidden Card Error if  the opponent acknowledges the action or controls the continuous effect modifying the game rule that was violated. This infraction only applies when a card whose identity is known to only one player is in a hidden set of cards both beforeand after the error.
>
> (...)
>
> **Upgrade**
>
> If a face-down card cast using a morph ability is discovered during the game to not have a morph ability, the penalty is a Game Loss. If the player has one or more cards   with a morph ability in hand, has not added previously unknown cards to their hand since casting the card found in violation, and has discovered the error themselves, the upgrade does not apply and they may swap the card for a card with the morph ability in hand

This is reinforced by rule 707.9 of the [Magic Comprehensive rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190823.pdf).

> 707.9. If a face-down permanent moves from the battlefield to any other zone, its owner must reveal it to all players as theymove it. If a face-down spell moves from the stack to any zone other than the battlefield, its owner must reveal it to all playersas theymove it. **If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents and spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players. At the end of each game, all face-down permanents and spells must be revealed to all players.**

Comment: That's an old version of the guide, the new version is: https://media.wpn.wizards.com/attachements/mtg_ipg_12jul19_en.pdf and the section you'd want to reference is 2.3 Game Play Error — Hidden Card Error

Comment: @firedraco Fixed

Comment: It seems a little weird to say that the comprehensive rules "reinforce" the IPG. The comprehensive rules are the core rules, and the IPG is about how to enforce the rules.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the question is tagged with "mtg-regular-rel", and Regular REL is a rules enforcement level the IPG doesn't apply to. Even more so, it doesn't apply to kitchen table Magic (which you didn't claim, but I'll add for completeness's sake).

Comment: Right, for regular REL, the document that applies is [Judging at Regular REL](https://wpn.wizards.com/en/document/magic-gathering-judging-regular-rel) instead of the IPG.

Comment: Could a player abuse the section described in Upgrade by having two creatures with Morph in hand which could be useful in different situations, playing a land face down as a creature with Morph, then at the end of the opponent's next turn (i.e. with more information) "realizing" their own "mistake" and replacing the land with the creature that is now most convenient?

Comment: If they do that accidentally, then they must call a judge, who will give them a Warning and allow them to correct the problem. If they actually did it on purpose, then this is cheating and should result in disqualification, but it's true that they might fool the judge. However, they would still get a Warning for the Hidden Card Error, even though under the circumstances it would not be upgraded to a Game Loss. It seems unlikely that a cheater could get away with such a remarkable “accident” more than once.

Comment: The text that you've quoted doesn't seem to support your initial summary. You write "Failing to reveal a face down creature with Morph at the end of the game is treated as a Game Loss"; but the text that you quote says that this is only a *Warning*, and only becomes a "Game Loss" if it's discovered that the face-down creature really *doesn't* have Morph.

Comment: I remember that this type of problem arose from what was the first card with a morph-like ability:Illusionary Mask.One of the currentRulings ofIM reads:"If you use the ability to cast aCreatureCardFaceDown,you must keep track of the amount and types ofMana you spent on X.If that creature spell is moved from the stack to anywhere other than the battlefield, the resulting creature leaves the battlefield,orGame ends, the face-down card is revealed.If itsManaCost couldn't be paid by some amount of,or all of,theMana you spent on X,all applicable penalties for casting a card illegally are assessed".

Comment: Imagining that the part concerning the loss of the game also applies to all actual cards with morph, that is very similar to Illusionary Mask ability,I believe this is the right treatment to be reserved for cheaters.